# Data preprocessing for LSTM training

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, training-data

I'm running into an issue while training an LSTM neural network.

For an MLP network, I used to input an array containing arrays representing the patterns. However, LSTMs require a specific input matrix shape—a tensor with three dimensions: (number of patterns, number of time steps, number features per time step (i.e., 1 here)). The problem arises because it seems impossible to create such an array when the number of time steps changes for each pattern, and without using padding.

To illustrate, consider the array [np.array([8, 7, 6]), np.array([9, 8, 0, 5]), np.array([1, 2])]. We aim to obtain the array:

```
[[[8.]   [7.]   [6.]]
 [[9.]   [8.]   [0.]   [5.]]
 [[1.]   [2.]]]
```

It appears challenging to achieve this structure with numpy arrays, as numpy does not allow for an attribute in np.shape() to vary. I've also explored TensorFlow's tensor objects without success. I'm struggling to figure out how to make our LSTM work seamlessly with patterns that don't share the same number of time steps.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions, thank you !

Comment: See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/understanding_masking_and_padding